# No overload matches this call for using any[] instead of any in Angular when displaying data in app.component.html and app.component.ts

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rest

I am fairly new to angular, I am using **Angular 15**, I basically have an Rest API response that I want to parse and show in the UI using angular. For that I used `HttpClient` and `GET` request to parse the response.

The code for `app.component.ts` is:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})



export class AppComponent{

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}
  posts: any[] = [];
  loadPosts(){
    this.http
    .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .subscribe((posts: any[])=>{
      this.posts=posts;
    });
  }
}
```

**EDIT** I changed the link for the get request call so that it can actually be used.

The code for `app.component.html` is:

```
This is a template for app component html
<br>
<button type="button" (click)="loadPosts()" class="btn btn-primary">Get Response Body</button>

<br>
<div *ngFor="let post of posts">
  <h1>{{ posts.includes }}</h1>
  <p> {{ posts.keys }} </p>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I am trying to get certain values from the response like `includes` and `keys` from the API call that I want to parse and show in the UI. That's why I used ngFor to iterate through the response and show only those sections.

My main issue is I'm getting this error:

```
src/app/app.component.ts:19:16 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(observer?: Partial<Observer<Object>> | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Type '(posts: any[]) => void' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<Observer<Object>>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(next: (value: Object) => void): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(posts: any[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'posts' and 'value' are incompatible.
        The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
          Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(next?: ((value: Object) => void) | null | undefined, error?: ((error: any) => void) | null | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | null | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(posts: any[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'posts' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
          The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?

19     .subscribe((posts: any[])=>{
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

When I use `[]` In

```
.get('https://cdn.contentful.com/myCustomApiLink')
    .subscribe((posts: any[])=>{
      this.posts=posts;
```

but without using `[]` I'm getting error:

```
app.component.ts:19 ERROR Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
    at DefaultIterableDiffer.diff (core.mjs:28817:19)
    at NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.mjs:3213:42)
    at callHook (core.mjs:2758:18)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:2717:17)
    at executeCheckHooks (core.mjs:2649:5)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:12084:21)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:13208:13)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:11865:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:12125:13)
    at detectChangesInternal (core.mjs:13352:9)
load (async)        
loadPosts   @   app.component.ts:19
AppComponent_Template_button_click_2_listener   @   app.component.html:3
Show 82 more frames
```

in the console.

Any Help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a sample response what you are getting from the API for `posts`

Comment: Here is the sample response:
`{
  "sys": {
    "type": "Array"
  },
  "total": 1,
  "skip": 0,
  "limit": 100,
  "items": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "tags": []
      },
      "sys": {
        "space": {
          "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Space",
            "id": "8utyj17y1gom"
          }
        },
        "id": "2kJUAOrtKyFg1cZR4k2kKL",
        "type": "Entry",
        "createdAt": "2020-04-06T14:33:34.889Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-10-17T17:26:10.168Z",
        "environment": {
          "sys": {`

Comment: It was too long to paste the whole thing, but I basically need the following to be parsed:

`fields": {
          "entryTitle": "Support",
          "title": "Help & Support",
          "description": "Need help and support with products and services? Check out our FAQs, diagnostic tools, how-to articles, troubleshooting tips, Community Forums and more. ",
          "isNoIndex": false`

@DanPhilipBejoy

Comment: Its supposed to be an array of objects but the response is one big object hence the type error.

Answer (score 1):

Since the API is returning an object there is a mismatch between the response type and the type mentioned.

The required array seems to be a part of the response, So try piping the response before subscribing to it to get just the required array.

```
this.http.get('https://cdn.contentful.com/myCustomApiLink')
  .pipe(
      map((data: any) => data.items),
      catchError(error => { return throwError('Error') }))
  .subscribe((posts: any[]) => {
      this.posts = posts;
  });
```

Comment: I removed the actual link and replaced it with `myCustomApiLink`  since it contained some data I didn't want to be accessible. using any gives error on the console it does not work.

Comment: What error are you getting when you gave type `any`.

Comment: I added the error in the last part of my explanation in the main problem statement, it is giving `app.component.ts:19 ERROR Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
    at DefaultIterableDiffer.diff (core.mjs:28817:19)` I added the full log at the last part of the explanation

Comment: I also changed the get url so that you can actually try it out. Thanks!

Comment: @fsaa Even the new API returns an object rather than an array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249793/discussion-between-fsaa-and-dan-philip-bejoy).

Answer (score 1):

You have to type the `get` method

```
this.http
.get<any>('https://cdn.contentful.com/myCustomApiLink')
.subscribe((posts: any[])=>{
  this.posts=posts;
});
```

I would suggest not using `any` at all

Comment: Thanks! That got rid of the error but I still get the error `app.component.ts:19 ERROR Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed     at DefaultIterableDiffer.diff (core.mjs:28817:19)` now when I click on the button to display the response.

If I were to use something else instead of `any` can you suggest what that would be.

Comment: I changed the get request url so that it can actually be used.

Comment: What does `console.log(posts)` print?